# Quick method using POSIX tools to generate a random file

Tags: linux, posix

So I'm using a board on a ramfs that is pretty much running a barebones Linux kernel that is pretty much just POSIX-compliant (with busybox).  For some disk drive testing, I am trying to generate a large (on the order of a Gigabyte) random file.

Currently what I'm doing is as follows:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=./basefile bs=1M count=10
for i in {1..100}; do cat ./basefile >> ./testFile; done
```

Thus I have a practical solution that meets my needs.

However, on a more academic note, is there an efficient way to generate completely (psuedo-)random files using POSIX utilities only?  Openssl is not installed.  For the sake of comparison, above command runs in 23.5s, while below command runs in 3m3.179s:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=./testFile bs=1M count=1000
```

Comment: You know urandom needs its entropy pool filled to be fast right? Don't just leave it idling away.

Comment: @micke I thought that that was random (and urandom just looped over whatever random data it had or something like that).

Comment: @micke urandom doesn't care about entropy, you're confusing with `/dev/random`.